# Dynamically update style of control in UWP via a trigger

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to display the `style` of a control in a template depending on an `enum` in the used class. I tried to use [this to use the enum in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279602/how-can-i-use-enum-types-in-xaml) and [this to create a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648456/uwp-style-trigger-missing). The problem is that I cannot use `x:Static` in UWP and the trigger is never fired. My workaround does not work either.

My class:

```cs
//Namespace Enums
public enum ConnectionState
{
    Open,
    Closed,
    Connecting,
    Broken
}

//Namespace Models
public class DatabaseConnection : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ConnectionState _connectionState = ConnectionState.Broken;
    public ConnectionState ConnState
    {
        get => _connectionState;
        set
        {
            if (value != _connectionState)
            {
                _connectionState = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ConnStateInt));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InfoBadgeStyle));
            }
        }
    }

    public int ConnStateInt => (int)ConnState;

    public Style InfoBadgeStyle
    {
        get
        {
            return ConnState switch
            {
                ConnectionState.Open => (Style)Application.Current.Resources["SuccessIconInfoBadgeStyle"],
                ConnectionState.Connecting => (Style)Application.Current.Resources["AttentionIconInfoBadgeStyle"],
                ConnectionState.Broken => (Style)Application.Current.Resources["CriticalIconInfoBadgeStyle"],
                _ => (Style)Application.Current.Resources["InformationalIconInfoBadgeStyle"],
            };
        }
    }
}
```

My template:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ConnectionTemplate" x:DataType="models:DatabaseConnection">
        <muxc:InfoBadge Style="{x:Bind InfoBadgeStyle}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

How can I update the style with a trigger in UWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear why you have both an `InfoBadgeStyle` property and triggers in XAML but if you want your `ChangePropertyActions` to be able to set the `Style` property, you should not set the local `Style` property like this as it will take precedence:

```
<muxc:InfoBadge ... Style="{x:Bind InfoBadgeStyle}">
```

So either remove the `InfoBadgeStyle` property or remove the triggers.

Also note that `x:Bind` binds `OneTime` by default so if you want to react to change notifications you should set the `Mode` to `OneWay`: `Style="{x:Bind InfoBadgeStyle, Mode=OneWay}"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The point because I implemented the triggers is that the solution from you does not work. It is not doing anything on a property change.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: When you change the values of a property, no event for the UI is raised.

Comment: What property are you setting? `InfoBadgeStyle`?

Comment: Yes, I’m using `InfoBadgeStyle`.

Comment: `x:Bind` binds `OneTime` by default so if you want to react to change notifications you should set the `Mode` to `OneWay`: `Style="{x:Bind InfoBadgeStyle, Mode=OneWay}"`.

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thank you!